# numpy.unravel_index not returning expected row indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the output of [unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) in the context of the following bit of code.

Using [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) I create two arrays representative of some coordinates:

```
import numpy as np

x_in=np.arange(-800, 0, 70)
y_in=np.arange(-3500, -2000, 70)
y, x =np.meshgrid(y_in,x_in,indexing='ij')
```

I then run through one of the grids to identify values within certain limits:

```
limit=100
x_gd=x[np.logical_and(x>=-600-limit,x<=-600+limit)]
```

This returns an array with the values I'm interested in - to get the indices of these values I use the following function (which I developed after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251541/numpy-for-every-element-in-one-array-find-the-index-in-another-array)):

```
def get_index(array, select_array):
    ''' 
    Find the index positions of values from select_array in array
    ''' 
    rows,cols=array.shape
    flt = array.flatten()
    sorted = np.argsort(flt)
    pos = np.searchsorted(flt[sorted], select_array)
    indices = sorted[pos] 
    y_indx, x_indx = np.unravel_index(indices, [rows, cols])

    return y_indx, x_indx

    xx_y_indx, xx_x_indx = get_index(x, x_gd)
```

xx_x_indx returns what I expect - the col reference for the values from x:

```
array([2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3,
   4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2,
   3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

xx_y_indx however returns:

```
array([15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2,
   19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,
    2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19,
   15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19, 15,  2, 19], dtype=int64)
```

when I would expect it to show all rows as the coordinates represented by array x are identical every line - not just in rows 15, 2 and 19.

For what I'm interested in, I can just use the result of xx_x_indx - the column indices. However, I can't explain why the y (row) indices report as they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call to `searchsorted` is not finding the location of *every* occurrance of `selected_array` in `flt[sorted]`; it is finding the index of the *first* occurrance.

```
pos = np.searchsorted(flt[sorted], select_array)
```

---

```
In [273]: pos
Out[273]: 
array([44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66,
       88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44,
       66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88,
       44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88, 44, 66, 88])
```

Notice all the repeated values in `pos`.

---

Everything past this point is perhaps not what you intended, since you are not really working with all the locations of the `select_array` values in `flt[sorted]` or `array`.

---

You could fix the problem by using:

```
def get_index(array, select_array):
    ''' 
    Find the index positions of values from select_array in array
    '''
    mask = np.logical_or.reduce([array==val for val in np.unique(select_array)])
    y_indx, x_indx = np.where(mask)
    return y_indx, x_indx
```

or

```
def get_index2(array, select_array):
    idx = np.in1d(array.ravel(), select_array.ravel())
    y_indx, x_indx = np.where(idx.reshape(array.shape))
    return y_indx, x_indx
```

Which is faster depends on the number of elements in `np.unique(select_array)`. When this is large, using a `for-loop` is slower, and hence `get_index2` is faster. But if there are a lot of repeats in `select_array` and `np.unique(select_array)` is small, then `get_index` can be the faster option.

---

To demonstrate a use of `np.unravel_index`, you could even use

```
def get_index3(array, select_array):
    idx = np.in1d(array.ravel(), select_array.ravel())
    y_indx, x_indx = np.unravel_index(np.where(idx), array.shape)
    return y_indx, x_indx
```

but I think this is slower than `get_index2` in all cases since `reshape` is very fast so using `np.where` with `reshape` is faster than using `np.where` and `np.unravel_index`.