# Determine the shuffled indices of two lists/arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

As a challenge, I've given myself this problem:

Given 2 lists, A, and B, where B is a shuffled version of A, the idea is to figure out the shuffled indices.

For example:

```
A = [10, 40, 30, 2]
B = [30, 2, 10, 40]

result = [2,   3,    0,      1] 
        A[2]  A[3]   A[0]  A[1]
        ||     ||     ||    ||
        30      2     10    40
```

Note that ties for identical elements can be resolved arbitrarily.

I've come up with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830948/4909087) that involves the use of a dictionary to store indices. What other possible solutions does this problem have? A solution using a library also works. Numpy, pandas, anything is fine.

Comment: using the list comprehension    '[ A.index(x) for x in B ]' output is [2, 3, 0, 1]

Comment: @Kallz That's O(n^2). I think a dict is better.

Comment: [Numpy way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8251541/846892).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks! Although I would say Divakar's solution is clearer to understand.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Does [their own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678543/finding-indices-of-matches-of-one-array-in-another-array) counts? Note that the accepted solution is first link is also doing the same thing.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I salute your sleuthing skills...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That looks like a good dup. Think we should close this one.

Comment: @Divakar This is not a "numpy only" question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an improvement over your current solution, you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and avoid [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = [10, 40, 30, 2]
B = [30, 2, 10, 40]

idx = defaultdict(list)
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx[l].append(i)

res = [idx[l].pop() for l in B]
print(res)
```

---

Here are the timings for the two methods using the sample input given:

**Script used for testing**

```
from timeit import timeit


setup = """
from collections import defaultdict;
idx1 = defaultdict(list); idx2 = {}
A = [10, 40, 30, 2]
B = [30, 2, 10, 40]
"""

me = """
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx1[l].append(i)
res = [idx1[l].pop() for l in B]
"""

coldspeed = """
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx2.setdefault(l, []).append(i)
res = [idx2[l].pop() for l in B]
"""

print(timeit(setup=setup, stmt=me))
print(timeit(setup=setup, stmt=coldspeed))
```

**Results**

```
original: 2.601998388010543
modified: 2.0607256239745766
```

So it appears that using `defaultdict` actually yields a slight speed increase. This actually makes since though since `defaultdict` is implemented in C rather than Python. Not to mention that the attribute lookup of the original solution - `idx.setdefault1` - is costly.

Comment: Nice. Does it make a big difference?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Alright, I update with some timings if you wanna to take a look.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the neat answer.

Comment: @ChristianDean for '[ A.index(x) for x in B ]'  it give 0.569697856903

Comment: @Kallz I don't have time to confirm that right now, but I imagine that as the size of `A` and `B` increased the time spent searching for `x` in `A` using `index` would increase exponential.

Answer (score 8):

We can make use of [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with its optional `sorter` argument -

```
sidx = np.argsort(B)
out = sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A, sorter=sidx)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: A = [10, 40, 30, 2, 40]
    ...: B = [30, 2, 10, 40]
    ...: 

In [20]: sidx = np.argsort(B)

In [21]: sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A, sorter=sidx)]
Out[21]: array([2, 3, 0, 1, 3])
```

Comment: Just confirming, how does this handle duplicates?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Dups in `A`?

Comment: Yep, how is that handled?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Handles pretty gracefully :) Should I add  a sample for that?

Comment: Sure... please do.

Answer (score 3):

LOL

```
pd.Series(A).reset_index().set_index(0).ix[B].T.values[0]
#array([2, 3, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Probably should have kept pandas out of this :p

Comment: Keep your word. Or else.

Comment: Relax. I did say pandas. :p Here's my +1.

Comment: Congrats on the 10K dude :-) Just noticed you reached it.

Comment: A simpler pandas solution could be: `pd.Index(A).get_indexer_for(B)`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my question, I was able to solve this using a dictionary. I store the indices in a `dict` and then use a list comprehension to pop them out:

```
A = [10, 40, 30, 2]
B = [30, 2, 10, 40]

idx = {}
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx.setdefault(l, []).append(i)

res = [idx[l].pop() for l in B]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 0, 1]
```

This is better than the obvious `[A.index(x) for x in B]` because it is

1. linear
2. handles duplicates gracefully

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package has an efficient and general solution to this:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
result = npi.indices(A, B)
```

Note that it has a kwarg to set a mode for dealing with missing values; and it works with nd-arrays of any type just the same, as it does with 1d integer arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Since several very nice solutions were posted, I've taken the liberty of assembling some crude timings to compare each method.

**Script used for testing**

```
from timeit import timeit


setup = """
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
idx1 = defaultdict(list); idx2 = {}
A = [10, 40, 30, 2]
B = [30, 2, 10, 40]
"""

me = """
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx1[l].append(i)
res = [idx1[l].pop() for l in B]
"""

coldspeed = """
for i, l in enumerate(A):
    idx2.setdefault(l, []).append(i)
res = [idx2[l].pop() for l in B]
"""

divakar = """
sidx = np.argsort(B)
res = sidx[np.searchsorted(B,A, sorter=sidx)]
"""

dyz = """
res = pd.Series(A).reset_index().set_index(0).ix[B].T.values[0]
"""

print('mine:', timeit(setup=setup, stmt=me, number=1000))
print('coldspeed:', timeit(setup=setup, stmt=coldspeed, number=1000))
print('divakar:', timeit(setup=setup, stmt=divakar, number=1000))
print('dyz:', timeit(setup=setup, stmt=dyz, number=1000))
```

**Result/Output (run on Jupyter notebook server. 1000 loops)**

```
mine: 0.0026700650341808796
coldspeed: 0.0029303128831088543
divakar: 0.02583012101240456
dyz: 2.208147854078561
```

Here are some timings where the size of `A` is 100,000 random numbers. And `B` is its shuffled equivalent. The program was just too time and memory consuming. Also I *had* to reduce the number of loops to 100. Otherwise, everything is the same as above:

```
mine: 17.663535300991498
coldspeed: 17.11006522300886
divakar: 8.73397267702967
dyz: 44.61878849985078
```

Comment: Okay.. since you've done this much, can you try the same for a `random.randint()` array of size 100000, and its equivalent `random.shuffle()`'d version?

Comment: Ah, it looks exactly like I imagined.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yup. I figured numpy would come out on top with bigger input.