# Order one numpy array by another

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have an array that determines an ordering of elements:

```
order = [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

And then I want to sort another, larger array (containing only those elements):

```
a = np.array([4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3])
```

such that the element(s) that come first in `order` come first in the results, etc.
In straight Python, I would do this with a key function:

```
sorted(a, key=order.index)
[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2]
```

How can I do this (efficiently) with numpy?  Is there a similar notion of "key function" for numpy arrays?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 5):

#### Specific case : `Ints`

For `ints`, we could use [`bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
np.repeat(order,np.bincount(a)[order])
```

Sample run -

```
In [146]: sorted(a, key=order.index)
Out[146]: [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2]

In [147]: np.repeat(order,np.bincount(a)[order])
Out[147]: array([3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2])
```

#### Generic case

**Approach #1**

Generalizing for all dtypes with `bincount` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/ @Andras Deak
def argsort_unique(idx):
    n = idx.size
    sidx = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    sidx[idx] = np.arange(n)
    return sidx

sidx = np.argsort(order)
c = np.bincount(np.searchsorted(order,a,sorter=sidx))
out = np.repeat(order, c[argsort_unique(sidx)])
```

**Approach #2-A**

With `np.unique` and `searchsorted` for the case when all elements from `order` are in `a` -

```
unq, count = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
out = np.repeat(order, count[np.searchsorted(unq, order)])
```

**Approach #2-B**

To cover for all cases, we need one extra step -

```
unq, count = np.unique(a, return_counts=1)
sidx = np.searchsorted(unq, order)
out = np.repeat(order, np.where(unq[sidx] == order,count[sidx],0))
```

Comment: Okay, okay, that's crafty.  I'd like to do it for any type of value, but I'll give you partial credit.  :)  That gives me some ideas.

Comment: @DoctorJ Added few generic solutions.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Don't you mean `np.argsort(order).argsort()` being equivalent to `np.searchsorted(unq, order)`? That would be same as `@Doctor J's soln`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Divakar's solution, you can count how many times each element occurs and then repeat the ordered elements that many times:

```
c = Counter(a)
np.repeat(order, [c[v] for v in order])
```

(You could vectorize the count lookup if you like).  I like this because it's linear time, even if it's not pure numpy.

I guess a pure numpy equivalent would look like this:

```
count = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)[1]
np.repeat(order, count[np.argsort(np.argsort(order))])
```

But that's less direct, more code, and way too many sorts.  :)

Comment: Maybe this solution might also help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8251757

Comment: Using argsort to invert a permutation is wasteful. `invp = np.empty_like(p); invp[p] = np.arange(p.size)` does the same in linear time.

Comment: Oh that's a good trick.  Unfortunately, it's not a permutation (p may not be integral).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly direct conversion of your pure-Python approach into numpy. The key idea is replacing the `order.index` function with a lookup in a sorted vector. Not sure if this is any simpler or faster than the solution you came up with, but it may generalize to some other cases.

```
import numpy as np
order = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2])
a = np.array([4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3])  

# create sorted lookup vectors
ord = np.argsort(order)
order_sorted = order[ord]
indices_sorted = np.arange(len(order))[ord]

# lookup the index in `order` for each value in the `a` vector
a_indices = np.interp(a, order_sorted, indices_sorted).astype(int)

# sort `a` using the retrieved index values
a_sorted = a[np.argsort(a_indices)]
a_sorted

# array([3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2])
```

This is a more direct way (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16992713/3830997)), but it seems to be about 4 times slower than the `np.interp` approach:

```
lookup_dict = dict(zip(order, range(len(order))))
indices = np.vectorize(lookup_dict.__getitem__)(a)
a_sorted = a[np.argsort(indices)]
```