# Matplotlib set x tick labels does not swap order

Tags: matplotlib

I want to make a line graph where essentially (Dog,1), (Cat,2), (Bird,3) and so on are plotted and connected by line. In additional, I would like to be able to determine the order of the label in the X axis. Matplotlib auto-plotted with the order 'Dog', 'Cat', and 'Bird' label. Despite my attempt at re-arranging the order to 'Dog','Bird','Giraffe','Cat', the graph doesn't change (see image). What should I do to be able to arrange the graph accordingly?[image]

```
x = ['Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Cat','Cat']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x_ticks_labels = ['Dog','Bird','Giraffe','Cat']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) 
ax.plot(x,y)

# Set number of ticks for x-axis
ax.set_xticks(range(len(x_ticks_labels)))
# Set ticks labels for x-axis
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_labels)
```

Comment: There is no "Giraffe" in your `x` list. What exactly is your question? How should the desired figure look like?

Comment: @Bazingaa I assume the whole point of the question is the fact that Giraffe is not in `x` (besides the required custom ordering).

Comment: @Bazingaa apologies for the confusion, my purpose is to make the graph shown according to my determined label order instead of matplotlib's automatic ordering.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest answered the question. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use matplotlib's categorical feature

You may predetermine the order of categories on the axes by first plotting something in the correct order then removing it again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Cat','Cat']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x_ticks_labels = ['Dog','Bird','Giraffe','Cat']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) 

sentinel, = ax.plot(x_ticks_labels, np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(x_ticks_labels)))
sentinel.remove()
ax.plot(x,y, color="C0", marker="o")

plt.show()
```

#### Determine indices of values

The other option is to determine the indices that the values from `x` would take inside of `x_tick_labels`. There is unfortunately no canonical way to do so; here I take the 
solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297636/4124317) using `np.where`. Then one can simply plot the `y` values against those indices and set the ticks and ticklabels accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Bird','Dog','Cat','Cat','Cat']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x_ticks_labels = ['Dog','Bird','Giraffe','Cat']

xarr = np.array(x)
ind = np.where(xarr.reshape(xarr.size, 1) == np.array(x_ticks_labels))[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) 

ax.plot(ind,y, color="C0", marker="o")
ax.set_xticks(range(len(x_ticks_labels)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_labels)

plt.show()
```

#### Result in both cases

[image]