# How to remove repeating and empty or unmarked values on subplot of x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, x-axis

I'm developing a set of graphs to paint some Pandas DataFrame values. For that I'm using various pandas, numpy and matplotlib modules and functions using the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
    
    data = {'Name': ['immoControlCmd', 'BrkTerrMde', 'GlblClkYr', 'HsaStat', 'TesterPhysicalResGWM', 'FapLc','FirstRowBuckleDriver', 'GlblClkDay'],
            'Value': [0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            'Id_Par': [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
            }
    
    signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    
    def plot_signals(signals_df):
        # Count signals by par
        signals_df['Count'] = signals_df.groupby('Id_Par').cumcount().add(1).mask(signals_df['Id_Par'].eq(0), 0)
        # Subtract Par values from the index column
        signals_df['Sub'] = signals_df.index - signals_df['Count']
        id_par_prev = signals_df['Id_Par'].unique()
        id_par = np.delete(id_par_prev, 0)
        signals_df['Prev'] = [1 if x in id_par else 0 for x in signals_df['Id_Par']]
        signals_df['Final'] = signals_df['Prev'] + signals_df['Sub']
        # signals_df['Finall'] = signals_df['Final'].unique()
        # print(signals_df['Finall'])
        # Convert and set Subtract to index
        signals_df.set_index('Final', inplace=True)
        # pos_x = len(signals_df.index.unique()) - 1
        # print(pos_x)
    
        # Get individual names and variables for the chart
        names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
        num_names_list = len(names_list)
        num_axis_x = len(signals_df["Name"])
    
        # Creation Graphics
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=num_names_list, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True)
        plt.xticks(np.arange(0, num_axis_x), color='SteelBlue', fontweight='bold')
        for pos, (a_, name) in enumerate(zip(ax, names_list)):
            # Get data
            data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
            # Get values axis-x and axis-y
            x_ = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
            # print(data.index.values)
            y_ = np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
            # Plotting the data by position
            ax[pos].plot(x_, y_, drawstyle='steps-post', marker='*', markersize=8, color='k', linewidth=2)
            ax[pos].set_ylabel(name, fontsize=8, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=30, labelpad=35)
            ax[pos].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
            ax[pos].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
            ax[pos].grid(alpha=0.4, color='SteelBlue')
        plt.show()
    
    
    plot_signals(signals_df)
```

What I want is to remove the points or positions of the x-axis where nothing is painted or they are not marked on the graph, but leave the values ​​and names as in the image at the end; Seen from Pandas it would be the "Final" column that, before painting the subplots, assigned it as an index and it is where some of the values ​​in this column are repeated; would be to remove the values ​​enclosed in the red box from the graph, but leave the values ​​and names as in the image at the end:

```
                            Name  Value  Id_Par  Count  Sub  Prev
     Final                                                       
     0            immoControlCmd      0       0      0    0     0
     1                BrkTerrMde      5       0      0    1     0
     2                 GlblClkYr      0       3      1    1     1
     2                   HsaStat      4       3      2    1     1
     2      TesterPhysicalResGWM      0       3      3    1     1
     2                     FapLc      1       3      4    1     1
     6      FirstRowBuckleDriver      1       0      0    6     0
     7                GlblClkDay      1       0      0    7     0
```

[image: actual chart]

I've been trying to bring the unique values ​​of the last column, which would be the value that the x-axis should be, but since the dataframe is of another size or dimension, I get an error: `ValueError: Length of values ​​(5) does not match length of index (8)`, and then I have to resize my chart, but in this case I don't understand how to do it:

```
        signals_df['Final'] = signals_df['Prev'] + signals_df['Sub']
        signals_df['Finall'] = signals_df['Final'].unique()
        print(signals_df['Finall'])
```

I've also tried to bring the size of the unique index, previously assigned to apply a subtraction to data.index.values ​​of the variable x_, but it does not bring me what I want because it is gathering all the values ​​and subtracting them in bulk and not separately , as is data.index.values:

```
    signals_df.set_index('Final', inplace=True)
    pos_x = len(signals_df.index.unique()) - 1
    ...
    ..
    .
         x_ = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values-pos-x, len(signals_df) - 1])
```

**Is there a Pandas and/or Matplotlib function that allows me? or Could someone give me a suggestion that will help me better understand how to do it? what I expect to achieve would be the plot below**:

[image: expected chart]

I really appreciate your help, any comments help.
I've Python version: 3.6.5, Pandas version: 1.1.5 and Matplotlib version: 3.3.2

Comment: if you made your `x_` values into strings, you could plot them as categorical data, as they do in this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py

Comment: Thanks @tmdavision, but in the example they separate the subplots into 2 lines and what I want is that it be the same line of steps, minus the values ​​that are empty, using pandas and/or if possible matplotlib. And it is required to disappear or delete the x-axis values ​​that have no marks on the plot.

Comment: You can do that with catagorical plotting, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this is if you make your x-axis values into strings, which means that matplotlib will make a "categorical" plot. [See examples of that here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py)

For your case, because you have subplots which would have different values, and they are not always in the right order, we need to do a bit of trickery first to make sure the ticks appear in the correct order. For that, we can use the approach [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593841/588071), where they plot something that uses all of the x values in the correct order, and then remove it.

To gather all the xtick values together, you can do something like this, where you create a list of the values, reduce it to the unique values using a `set`, then sort those values, and convert to strings using a list comprehension and `str()`:

```
# First make a list of all the xticks we want
xvals = [-1,]
for name in names_list:
    xvals.append(signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"].index.values[0])
xvals.append(len(signals_df)-1)

# Reduce to only unique values, sorted, and then convert to strings
xvals = [str(i) for i in sorted(set(xvals))]
```

Once you have those, you can make a dummy plot, and then remove it, like so (this is to fix the tick positions in the correct order). **NOTE that this needs to be inside your plotting loop for matplotlib versions 3.3.4 and earlier**:

```
# To get the ticks in the right order on all subplots, we need to make
# a dummy plot here and then remove it
dummy, = ax[0].plot(xvals, np.zeros_like(xvals))
dummy.remove()
```

Finally, when you actually plot the real data inside the loop, you just need to convert `x_` to strings as you plot them:

```
ax[pos].plot(x_.astype('str'), y_, drawstyle='steps-post', marker='*', markersize=8, color='k', linewidth=2)
```

Note the only other change I made was to not explicitly set the xtick positions (which you did, with `plt.xticks`), but you can still use that command to set the font colour and weight

```
plt.xticks(color='SteelBlue', fontweight='bold')
```

And this is the output:

[image]

For completeness, here I have put it all together in your script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)

data = {'Name': ['immoControlCmd', 'BrkTerrMde', 'GlblClkYr', 'HsaStat', 'TesterPhysicalResGWM', 'FapLc',
                 'FirstRowBuckleDriver', 'GlblClkDay'],
        'Value': [0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        'Id_Par': [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
        }

signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def plot_signals(signals_df):
    # Count signals by par
    signals_df['Count'] = signals_df.groupby('Id_Par').cumcount().add(1).mask(signals_df['Id_Par'].eq(0), 0)
    # Subtract Par values from the index column
    signals_df['Sub'] = signals_df.index - signals_df['Count']
    id_par_prev = signals_df['Id_Par'].unique()
    id_par = np.delete(id_par_prev, 0)
    signals_df['Prev'] = [1 if x in id_par else 0 for x in signals_df['Id_Par']]
    signals_df['Final'] = signals_df['Prev'] + signals_df['Sub']
    # signals_df['Finall'] = signals_df['Final'].unique()
    # print(signals_df['Finall'])
    # Convert and set Subtract to index
    signals_df.set_index('Final', inplace=True)
    # pos_x = len(signals_df.index.unique()) - 1
    # print(pos_x)

    # Get individual names and variables for the chart
    names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
    num_names_list = len(names_list)
    num_axis_x = len(signals_df["Name"])

    # Creation Graphics
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=num_names_list, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True)

    # No longer any need to define where the ticks go, but still set the colour and weight here
    plt.xticks(color='SteelBlue', fontweight='bold')

    # First make a list of all the xticks we want
    xvals = [-1, ]
    for name in names_list:
        xvals.append(signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"].index.values[0])
    xvals.append(len(signals_df) - 1)

    # Reduce to only unique values, sorted, and then convert to strings
    xvals = [str(i) for i in sorted(set(xvals))]

    for pos, (a_, name) in enumerate(zip(ax, names_list)):
    
        # To get the ticks in the right order on all subplots,
        # we need to make a dummy plot here and then remove it
        dummy, = ax[pos].plot(xvals, np.zeros_like(xvals))
        dummy.remove()
        # Get data
        data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
        # Get values axis-x and axis-y
        x_ = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
        y_ = np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
        # Plotting the data by position
        # NOTE: here we convert x_ to strings as we plot, to make sure they are plotted as catagorical values
        ax[pos].plot(x_.astype('str'), y_, drawstyle='steps-post', marker='*', markersize=8, color='k', linewidth=2)
        ax[pos].set_ylabel(name, fontsize=8, fontweight='bold', color='SteelBlue', rotation=30, labelpad=35)
        ax[pos].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
        ax[pos].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
        ax[pos].grid(alpha=0.4, color='SteelBlue')

    plt.show()


plot_signals(signals_df)
```

Comment: Ready, thanks @tmdavison. Only a question, What does this do `.index.values[0]` inside the line of the first for loop?

Comment: `signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"].index.values` is basically what you use to make your `x_` array inside your plotting loop. So I used the same logic to make the xvals. The `[0]` is needed because without it, you get a 1-item numpy array, but we just want the value inside the array to make the xvals list.

Comment: Ok, ok... and one last question, why `np.zeros_like(x_values)` in the line: `dummy, = ax[pos].plot(x_values, np.zeros_like(x_values))`?

Comment: Could have used anything there really, as long as it was the same length as `x_vals`. I just wanted to use zeros so the y-axis scale wasn't affected