# Turning each element in a numpy array into its index in another array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I turn each element in a numpy array into its index in another array?

Take the following example. Let `a = np.array(["a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "a"])` and `b = np.array(["b", "c", "a"])`. How can I turn each element in `a` into its index in `b` to obtain `c = np.array([2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: For every element in one array, find the index in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251541/numpy-for-every-element-in-one-array-find-the-index-in-another-array) - particularly https://stackoverflow.com/a/8251668/463796

Answer (score 2):

**We can solve this problem in easy way as follow using Dictionary in python**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(["a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "a"])

b = np.array(["b", "c", "a"])

# Create hashmap/dictionary to store indexes 
hashmap ={}
for index,value in enumerate(b):
    hashmap[value]=index

# Create empty np array to store results
c=np.array([])

# Check the corresponding index using hashmap and append to result
for value in a:
    c= np.append(c,hashmap[value])
```

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve this using only numpy and without for loops

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in a:
  for i, val in enumerate(b):
    if val == j:
      print(i)
```